# Dividing the training/validation sets by spatial parcellation using KMeans: making sure each subset of training/validation includes all labels

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means, image-segmentation

I am hoping to get some help here. I want to use Kmeans clustering to divide the training set for the supervised learning in the next stage, which is called `spatial parcellation` in the literature.

I have extracted features (`X_train`) from 3D image data (within a dilated mask), which includes the x, y, and z (positions of voxels), and mask includes two labels (`y_train={0 : background,1: obj1}`). It means each voxel can be background or object with the mask

[image]

I used Kmeans clustering in scikit-learn, and clustered the training dataset's voxel position (`[x,y,z]`) into 80 different clusters.

**Problem** the problem is that once I have divided the training set based on 80 clusters,

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
pos_ind=[0,1,2]
kmeans_model= KMeans(n_clusters=80, random_state=rng).fit(X_TRAIN[:,pos_ind])
```

later I load the `kmeans_model` and assign the validation set to the clusters:

```
Dval_clusters = kmeans_model.predict(X_DVAL[:, pos_ind])
```

and then I find the row indices of validation set that it falls into `cidx` th cluster

```
cluster_idx = np.unique(kmeans_model.labels_) 
Dval_rows = np.where(Dval_clusters==cluster_idx[cidx])[0]  # find the rows of X_dval that belongs to cidx th cluster
X_dval = X_Dval[Dval_rows]
y_dval = y_Dval[Dval_rows]
```

Once I am fitting the validation set on the trained model, the trained model may have both labels `0` and `1`, however, it is showing an error during the fitting the `validation` set, which means during assigning the validation samples to a cluster, it has only picked up voxels either with `background` or `obj` voxels (i.e., all samples in one validation set of a cluster has only 1 class label).

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (30527,1) into shape (30527,2)
```

**Question** I know that clustering does not use labels, but is it possible to enforce the clustering that during the clustering, both labels are sampled? Or is there any trick for doing so? because background is just a class label and we need to to separate the object class (class:1) from the background (class:0)

I would really appreciate if you leave your expert opinion here.